# How to create a login system with PHP, MYSQL, & HTML through creating a SESSION

Tags: php, html, sql, session, phpmyadmin

I need to create a login system, where once logged in, depending on the user type, users will be able to access certain pages. I also need to ensure that these users are able to logout of their accounts. 
I will be using a phpmyadmin database to store the user data, and their user type.

I have attempted to create this, however my current code does not work at all. Despite the users having a record in phpmyadmin, and with a defined user type; I am unable to login using their details. Instead I am presented with an error message, stating that the account cannot be located.
I understand that the best way resolve this issue, is to implement a SESSION into my code, so users are not only able to login but their user type is remembered throughout their session.

How can I implement a SESSION into my code? Does anyone have any advice? Also I'm new to slack- please let me know if you have any questions on the above. Thanks

Comment: '*I have attempted to create this, however my current code does not work at all.*' - Include your errors and take the [tour].

Comment: show your code and what doesnt work?  DO it in steps, dont try to implement the entire thing all at once, make sure each step works

Comment: *"a phpmyadmin database"* - remember that episode of the Simpsons (the Cape Fear spoof) where Sideshow Bob keeps getting whacked in the face as he stands on rakes, you know that "Eueueueueuueuerrrhgghghgh" he mutters ... that's how I feel every time someone says *phpmyadmin database* - PHPMyAdmin is a web-based GUI for managing a MySQL (or MariaDB) database server - it is *not* a database itself. </rant>

Comment: _"an error message, stating that the account cannot be located"_ Surely you wrote that error message somewhere while building the login system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using SESSION stuff you need to start every page.php by:

```php
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

After what, you can cast some $_SESSION variable like:

```php
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Alex';
$_SESSION['online'] = TRUE;
```

So you could use it :

```php
<?php
   if($_SESSION['online']){ echo 'You are online';}
?>
```

And to disconnect someone from the sessions

```php
<?php session_start();
  $_SESSION = array(); //to delete every $_SESSION variables
  session_destroy();
?>
```

For the rest of your ask, it's way too long to explain it there. You should follow some tutorial.